# How to replace a table on a button click

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently having a problem on a homework assignment for my Intro to Web Design class. It's sort of an intro to javascript assignment. The point of the assignment is to calculate depreciation. We have fields to input Asset Value, Asset Life, and Salvage Value. There is also a button labeled "Calculate" that runs the formula to calculate straight line depreciation, and then generates a table with the correct results. My problem comes from clicking the calculate button more than once. When clicked again, my program prints more rows below the original, and will continue that as long as you click calculate. What I want to happen is that everytime calculate is clicked, it destroys the original table, and reprints another one. I just have no clue how to do that. Any help is appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

</style>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Homework 4</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function calculateAndDisplay() {
    var table = document.getElementById("depreciationTable");
    var assetValueInput  = document.getElementById("asset_value").value;
    var assetLifeInput   = document.getElementById("asset_life").value;
    var salvageValueInput = document.getElementById("salvage_value").value;
    var year;
    var assetValue = assetValueInput;
    var assetLife = assetLifeInput;
    var salvageValue = salvageValueInput;

    assetValue = assetValue - salvageValue;
    var depreciation = assetValue / assetLife;
    var accumulatedDepreciation = 0;
    var i;
    for(i=0; i < assetLifeInput; i++){
    year = i + 1;
    assetValue = assetValue - depreciation;
    accumulatedDepreciation = accumulatedDepreciation + depreciation;
    var row = table.insertRow(-1);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    if (year % 2 === 0){
        cell1.innerHTML = year;
        cell1.style.backgroundColor = "#ADD8E6";
        cell2.innerHTML = parseFloat(Math.round(assetValue * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
        cell2.style.backgroundColor = "#ADD8E6";
        cell3.innerHTML = parseFloat(Math.round(depreciation * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
        cell3.style.backgroundColor = "#ADD8E6";
        cell4.innerHTML = parseFloat(Math.round(accumulatedDepreciation * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
        cell4.style.backgroundColor = "#ADD8E6";
    }else{


    cell1.innerHTML = year;
    cell2.innerHTML = parseFloat(Math.round(assetValue * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
    cell3.innerHTML = parseFloat(Math.round(depreciation * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
    cell4.innerHTML = parseFloat(Math.round(accumulatedDepreciation * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
    }
    }


}
</script>
</head>
<body>
Asset Value: <input id="asset_value" type="text"/>
Asset Life: <input id="asset_life" type="text" />
Salvage Value: <input id="salvage_value" type="text"/>
<button onclick="calculateAndDisplay()">Calculate</button>
<table id="depreciationTable">
  <tr bgcolor= "#00008B">
    <td><font color="white">Year</font></td>
    <td><font color="white">Asset Value</font></td>
    <td><font color="white">Depreciation</font></td>
    <td><font color="white">Accumulated Depreciation</font></td>

  </tr>

</table>
<br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code doesn't "print another table below the original". It just adds a row to the table.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorace. You are correct

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the table in a div with an ID or unique Class that you can then use to change the innerHTML ... the HTML going in being the new table; overwriting the table that was there.